# Filter ServiceBusTrigger Messages based on Message Metadata

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

According to the [documentation](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp) , Service Bus trigger provides several metadata properties. These properties can be used as part of binding expressions in other bindings or as parameters in the code. These properties are members of the Message class. Example:

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem,
    Int32 deliveryCount,
    DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
    string messageId,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Some code here
}
```

Is it possible for Service Bus Queues to automatically filter messages based metadata and accept only messages with e.g. certain `ContentType` or `SessionId` in a similar way as `Correlation` and `SQL Filters` in Topic Subscriptions?

Comment: I cant see of any way you could filter by metadata, however, this is what topics are for

Comment: Azure function trigger doesn't have a filtering capability. However, you can use a filtering feature in the Service Bus model, when the queue message is forwarded to the topic entity and based on the subscription filter is forwarded to the final queue where is your ServiceBusTrigger function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible as queues don’t support the filtering topics do. What you could do is use topics/subscriptions and auto-forward from the subscriptions to the queues so that the code that is designed to receive from the queues only could continue working as-is.

`SessionId` is an exception. Sessions are supported by queues but it’s more for processing and not filtering out messages.